# Can I agree to what I do not allow the sovereign?

Tags: theology, society, social-contract, hobbes

Suppose we enter a social contract to bring about some power

> Social contract arguments typically are that individuals have
> consented, either explicitly or tacitly, to surrender some of their
> freedoms and submit to the authority (of the ruler, or to the decision
> of a majority) in exchange for protection of their remaining rights or
> maintenance of the social order

And we permit certain acts from it, but there is a higher power: must I also permit it from that?

> the sovereign is **the final arbiter on all matters** ethical, religious,
> and political. One of the “diseases of a commonwealth,” Hobbes says,
> is the opinion that “every private man is Judge of Good and Evil
> actions” (L 365). In the state of nature, as we have seen, individuals
> possess the natural right to determine what is good for themselves,
> i.e., what is necessary for their own conservation. As long as
> individuals make such determinations, Hobbes believes, there will be a
> state of war.

I think Hobbes is suggesting we allow anything of the sovereign: that's what is meant by the sovereigns's "absolute power" (indeed, there is usually said to be no right to overthrow it). In which case the question is a nonsense.

But maybe there is some watered down and post Hobbesian version of his social contract where we grant only some rights, but *always and only to the greatest power*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140530/discussion-on-question-by-crazed-can-i-agree-to-what-i-do-not-allow-the-sovereig).

Answer (score -1):

According to Susanne Sreedhar, we are need not "obey" the sovereign: if it does not limit its power. So I need not be expected to submit to e.g. my punishment, but only because it makes no difference if I do.

So I have the right to disobey the absolute authority of the sovereign. But I think that, given only the sovereign is permitted to punish etc., no-one else may do those things I am permitted to refuse the sovereign. In which case no, what I refuse of the sovereign I cannot permit of others, if only because my disobedience is quite limited.